# Como desenhar uma barra de progresso?

Tags: c++

Olá. Estou usando o seguinte código para desenhar o plano de fundo da janela e a barra de progresso:

```
case WM_PAINT: {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

    BITMAP bm;
    HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP hbmOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hdcMem, imagemdeteste);
    GetObject(imagemdeteste, sizeof(bm), &bm);

    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, bm.bmWidth, bm.bmHeight, hdcMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);

    SelectObject(hdcMem, hbmOld);
    DeleteDC(hdcMem);

    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
    SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(75, 75, 75));
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
    Rectangle(hdc, 0, 0, WindowSize.cx, WindowSize.cy);

    /* AQUI COMEÇA O DESENHO DA BARRA DE PROGRESSO */
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
    SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(75, 75, 75));
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
    Rectangle(hdc,
        ProgressBarLocation.x, ProgressBarLocation.y,
        ProgressBarLocation.x + ProgressBarSize.cx, ProgressBarLocation.y + ProgressBarSize.cy
    );

    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
    SetDCPenColor(hdc, RGB(75, 75, 75));
    SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
    SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(75, 75, 75));
    Rectangle(hdc,
        (ProgressBarLocation.x + 1) + iProgressBarPadding, (ProgressBarLocation.y + 1) + iProgressBarPadding,
        (ProgressBarLocation.x + 1) + iProgressBarPadding + (((ProgressBarSize.cx - (2 * (1 + iProgressBarPadding))) * ProgressBarValue) / 100), (ProgressBarLocation.y - 1) - iProgressBarPadding + ProgressBarSize.cy
    );

    EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}
```

Para atualizar a barra de progresso eu uso o seguinte código:

```
ProgressBarValue = QUALQUER VALOR DE 0 A 100;
RedrawWindow(hWnd, 0, 0, RDW_INVALIDATE);
```

Esse código vai chamar WM_PAINT e eu estaria desenhando toda a janela novamente, até mesmo o plano de fundo. Eu gostaria de alterar somente os retângulos usados para fazer a barra de progresso. Ou é dessa forma que se faz?

Qual a maneira correta de fazer isso?

Comment: A forma que você esta utilizando acima é manual (você mesmo desenha o retangulo que é usado como barra de progresso), mas tem outra forma usando o PROGRESS_CLASS que é um controle do proprio Windows e que é bem mais fácil (Apenas sugestão).

Comment: Obrigado. Vou procurar sobre PROGRESS_CLASS.

Comment: Olá, no final da pagina http://zetcode.com/gui/winapi/controlsIII/ há uma boa explicação do uso do PROGRESS_CLASS